What can I check to diagnose an open neutral on an outlet circuit?
I had a problem just show up out of the blue. How I came to have this issue was when my wife ran the microwave. The outlet to the microwave runs along wall to the outlet for the fridge. Since she ran the microwave neither outlet is working now. They both have been working for years.
Once they stopped working I ran a tester on the outlet for fridge and it came up Open neutral, as well as the microwave outlet. So I killed the power and pulled both outlets out and checked the wires, everything seemed good, tested again and same issue came up.
So I ended up changing both outlets but instead of pressing in the wires I ended up hooking on screws instead. After new outlets I ran test again and still getting open neutral. Plug anything in and it don't work.
Trying to figure out how all of a sudden both outlets are saying open neutral now and not working. I ended up testing every outlet in the house and it's only the two having the issues.
Any ideas I can try before I end up having to rewire the two plugs? Any thing I miss on trying?

Did you check the neutral wire for that circuit in the service panel?

Seeing you changed the outlets and used the screws, the problem is probably some place else.  A junction box, another outlet on the same circuit, or at the panel.  There is also a chance you got wire eating mice in the walls.

I did not get into the panel to check anything. But I did go from breaker to breaker and turned on 1 by 1 and it seemed like the two outlets are on the same circuit and nothing else, it once ran to the garbage disposal then the dishwasher but they currently been tied in other direction in house.  Checking panel now

Neutral wires do NOT go through breakers - that's been prohibited by electric code for a long time.  Neutral wires connect to a bar in the electrcal panel.  It's possible that one wasn't tight or for some other reason has come loose.

I meant the breaker stuff to find out what outlets were connected to them two.

Are those the only outlets on the circuit?

Yes just the two

Thanks all for replying and shooting me some things to try. I ended up removing all the wires in the panel and re hooking up, same with the two outlets, now tester is yelling everything is correct. :)  what a headache but all working now. BTW this forum is awesome. So fast and so helpful.

Not a forum, anyways..   I took tour and will resolve

Modern electrical code requires the use of torque drivers to set the right torque/tightness to connections.  You probably had a loose connection, and redoing them, tighten it up.

@quill -- neutrals must go through all GFCI and many AFCI breakers in order for them to work at all.  (if you try doing otherwise, the breaker will tell you you've screwed up by tripping as soon as you put load on it)
